# Inability to call SPROC from Azure Logic Apps - can't find syntax for the parameters

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

**Statement of intent:**
I'm trying to automate a workflow, moving data periodically from a CSV in Sharepoint into a table in Azure SQL Database. I've gotten so far as 1) Formatting a JSON array, and 2) Creating a SPROC that successfully takes the text of the JSON Array, and imports it into the appropriate table.

*Array appears like:*
`JSON = [{"col1":"col1Data","col2":"col2Data", ...}, <600-some more iterations>]`

*Invocation of stored procedure in SQL Management Studio looks like:*
`EXECUTE SprocName @json=N'<text of JSON above>'`

===========================================
**Problem:**
Lack of documentation allowing me to properly format one of the following two SQL Connectors' parameters to link these two statements together:

Both [Execute a Query (v2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#execute-a-sql-query-(v2)) and [Execute a Stored Procedure (v2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#execute-stored-procedure-(v2)) require that parameters or query text be provided, but no indication of how said parameters should be formatted.

For example, in terms of executing a stored procedure that takes a single parameter @json, the following text "looks" correct, but results in an error:

"body": "@json=N'+@string(outputs('Convert_Rows_To_Json').body)+'"

Error:
Failed to save logic app UpdateDomainCoverage. The template validation failed: 'The template action 'Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)' at line '1' and column '3148' is not valid: "The template language expression 'json=N'+@string(outputs('Convert_Rows_To_Json').body)+'' is not valid: the string character '=' at position '4' is not expected.".'.

I've tried a number of variations, for both the @json parameter on Execute Stored Procedure, or simply building the query from whole cloth in Execute SQL, to no avail. Suggestions?

Comment: What if you just use @body('Convert_Rows_To_Json') ? I usually pick from the Designer so not sure if I have the proper syntax.  Just pick the Body from the Convert_Rows_To_Json step - is that a Compose?

Comment: Scott, that returns the same information as outputs('Convert_Rows_To_Json').body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the syntax. Didn't find any documentation, just tried working from one error message to another.

```
"Pump_data_into_target_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "json": "@{body('Pull_FeedbackItems_from_source').ResultSets['Table1']}"
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql_2']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('servername.database.windows.net'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('dbname'))}/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('sprocname'))}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Pull_FeedbackItems_from_Source": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
```

The fundamental answer to my question was: provide the parameter/value pairs as a JSON object. See the value of the "body" element in the listing above. For this to work, though, one also has to enter the "headers" element, which I didn't even see documented on the API call. Was led to that by an error message stating that the content type was plain text, when it was clearly json.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample from Code View of calling a stored procedure with parameter 'from' that takes a datetime value.  When you pick the sproc in the Designer it should show all the parameters for you to populate.

```
    "Get_jobs": {
        "inputs": {
            "body": {
                "from": "@{convertFromUtc( variables('SelectTime'), variables('timeZone'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}"
            },
            "host": {
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql_2']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "post",
            "path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[GetJobs]'))}"
        },
        "runAfter": {
            "Refresh_data_for_BI": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    },
```

Comment: Well, Scott, unfortunately I don't have the option to "pick the sproc in the Designer".

Trying to drop down "Name of stored procedure" responds:
Could not retrieve values. Cannot evaluate the parameter 'path.$.server' at design-time; it is empty or has a runtime expression.'

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've been messing with this on-and-off in between other tasks today, and finally got tired of trying to get it done in the input of the "Execute query".

**Brute Force Solution**: I added another Javascript step, with the following code:

```
var input = workflowContext.actions.Convert_Rows_To_Json.outputs.body;

var sqlQuery = 'EXECUTE [ImportDomainCoverage] N\'' + input + '\'';

return sqlQuery;
```

It's not pretty (one more step), but it works.

Now to see if I can modify things sufficiently to parameterize the table name, rather than needing six steps for each table.